# Replacement question

Tags: replacement

I have this equation

```
 F2 + F4 - V1 + V3==0
```

I want it to be converted automatically  via a replacement rule to

```
   Subscript[F, 2][x, t] + Subscript[F, 4][x, t] - 
  Subscript[V, 1][x, t] + Subscript[V, 3][x, t]==0
```

I have so many terms that's why I need the conversion to be automatic.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, unfortunately the accepted answer didn't warn you about that. My advice is to follow the advice from Bob Hanlon (+1) and use `Subscript` only for display.  The accepted answer does answer the request, but it's bad advice.

Answer (score 7):

It is generally much easier to work with indexed variables. You can [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) the display of the variables in any desired manner.

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {F, V};

eqn = F[2] + F[4] - V[1] + V[3] == 0
```

[image]

To add the variable dependencies

```
eqn2 = eqn /. sym_[int_] :> sym[int][x, t]
```

[image]

Or in situations where other similar forms are present that should not have the dependencies added, use the more specific

```
eqn2 = eqn /. sym_?(MemberQ[{F, V}, #] &)[int_Integer] :> 
  sym[int][x, t]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `sym_?(MemberQ[{F, V}, #] &)` you can use `(F | V)`

Answer (score 4):

First, pactelize the resource function `SymbolToSubscript` using `PacletizeResourceFunction` as follows:

```
ResourceFunction["PacletizeResourceFunction"]["SymbolToSubscript"]
```

Using `SymbolToSubscript` with your equation:

```
SymbolToSubscript[F2 + F4 - V1 + V3 == 0]
(*Subscript[F, 2] + Subscript[F, 4] - Subscript[V, 1] + Subscript[V, 3] == 0*)
```

Or without pacletize the resource function `SymbolToSubscript`:

```
ResourceFunction["SymbolToSubscript"][F2 + F4 - V1 + V3 == 0]
(*Subscript[F, 2] + Subscript[F, 4] - Subscript[V, 1] + Subscript[V, 3] == 0*)
```

Answer (score 3):

To give an answer, some more info is needed. I assume that the variable names consists of a character followed by a digit. Otherwise, the RegularExpression must be adapted. With this assumptions, we can define a function that does the replacements:

```
makeSub[ex_] := Module[{str = ToString[ex]},
  str = StringReplace[str, 
    RegularExpression["(\\w)(\\d)"] :>  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\($1\), \($2\)]\)"];
  ToExpression[str]
  ]
```

We may test with your example:

```
makeSub[F2 + F4 - V1 + V3 == 0 ]
```

[image]

To include the arguments we may define:

m

```
akeSub[ex_] := 
 Module[{str = ToString[ex]}, 
  str = StringReplace[str, 
    RegularExpression["(\\w)(\\d)"] :> 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\($1\), \($2\)]\)[x,t]"];
  ToExpression[str]]
makeSub[F2 + F4 - V1 + V3 == 0]
```

[image]